# inserting text in multiple files before a certain pattern

Tags: linux, sed

original file called `animals` looks like this:

```
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

This command works `sed '/dog/i\ Linux Scripting' animals`
by placing  `Linux Scripting` before `dog`and I get the following:

```
 Linux Scripting
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

However if I do a head on animals after this the file is unchanged.

```
$ head animals
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

How do I do this in such a way that it overwrites the existing file?

**Note:** for multiple files I would hope to relace `animals` with `*.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make in-file changes by using the `-i` option.

```
$ sed '/dog/i\ Linux Scripting' animals
 Linux Scripting
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

```
$ sed -i '/dog/i\ Linux Scripting' animals
```

```
$ cat animals
 Linux Scripting
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

From the `man` page:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

               edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

So you can create a backup of your original file by passing a suffix. This can be done by saying:

```
sed -i.bak '/dog/i\ Linux Scripting' animals
```

This will make in-file changes to your `animals` file but will create `animals.bak` file if you ever need the original file.